# Scifi book about small genetically engineered humans

Tags: story-identification, genetic-engineering

The story was about the human beings becoming too "static" in evolutionary terms. A scientist engineers much smaller human beings, that in their infancy are "about an inch high" (IIRC). This is, he says, to have the best ratio between the nervous system and the body they have to control.

This new race proves to be extremely smart, telepathic, and of course there's a military bad guy that opposes the project.
There are also three other bad guys, which are the typical not-so-smart-bad-guys, that in the very end

> get caught by the small humans and have their heads cut off.

Also at the end, something that I consider very silly is found out:

> the small humans have formed their own civilization, which is under control of a giant brain that they have built.

Any suggestion as to the title?

EDIT: Adding details to answer the comment, I've read it in the early 90s, but I think it was from the 80s. It was a full novel, and I think it was aimed at adults (but I was only 14 at the time).

Comment: When did you read it? How old is the story? Is it a short story, novella or full novel? Is it aimed at adults?

Comment: I've edited the question, thank you :-)

Comment: `have their head cut` Heads cut off?

Comment: @Mithrandir Yes, I clearly remember that these guys, possibly two men and a woman were captured, put on a medical bed, anesthetized, and the cutting of the head was described in only a few lines as extremely clean.

Comment: I think I have a book (and possibly a sequel) whose title includes "Micronauts".  A quick Google search turns up a lot of stuff related to the toys of the same name, and I don't have time here at work to sort through all that.  The book were from the 70s or early 80s.  Ah, here is the series: https://www.goodreads.com/series/57826-the-micronauts

Comment: @LAK I've had a look around and it looks similar but not exactly the same. I kind of remember the "Project Arcadia" though, so I guess I'll probably try and find a copy of that book to see if that's really the one. In case it is, you should know that you're practically a superhero for finding this out :-)

Comment: Glad to help.  I'll make my comment into an answer, in case it turns out to be correct.  I  read the 2 of those three books back in the early 1980s, but I don't remember enough about the plot (like the decapitations you mentioned) to know whether it's the right guess or not.  I just remember the books have nothing to do with the toys.

Comment: I've been looking for the exact same title for years (on and off). If anybody knows the title, this would be highly appreciated. If it is any help, I can provide a few more details avout the story. The first smaller human being created does not survive and dies of a cardiac arrest. The second and third ones survive and become the leaders of the new "species". IIRC, their names were Kapono and Modelo (sp?).

Answer (score 2):

I have the first two books in a trilogy by Gordon Williams, published in the  late 70s. The series is described [here](http://goodreads.com/series/57826-the-micronauts).  My only memories of the plot are that it was not related to the Mirconauts toys, and it involved miniature people.

Summary for first book, *[The Micronauts](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/874830.The_Micronauts)*:

> Earth's resources were exhausted. Civilization had collapsed. Food was a luxury in a world poisoned by chemical wastes and doomed by uncontrollable violence. Man's last hope was Project Arcadia, the bizarre experiment submitted to by a group of dedicated scientists. They were the new pioneers, risking their own lives to explore the strangest land that ever existed.

[image: Book cover]

Answer (score -1):

I believe it is [Hellstrom's Hive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellstrom%27s_Hive) you are looking for.

Comment: Why and how? Could you elaborate please? Even provide a link and a bio.